# Is it possible to make a function that can manipulate the object inside a particular function?

Tags: javascript, object

Lets say we have a function that has an object inside it and more :

```
 function myFunc() {
   var obj = {
     "one" : "1",
     "two" : "2"
   };
   // And more code is down here but our main focus is in the obj object.
 };
```

Now considering another function specially designed for the myFunc() which can either add or remove properties from the object obj in myFunc(). For example by considering the function manip() is that special function that can minuplate the obj object inside the function myFunc() :

```
 manip("add", {
  "three" : "3"
}; 
/* Now the obj object inside myFunc() becomes :
  var obj = {
    "one" : "1",
    "two" : "2",
    "three" : "3"
  }
```

Again :

```
 manip("remove", "one three");
 /* Now the obj object inside myFunc() becomes :
   var obj = {
    "two" : "2"
   }
```

So, can this be possible ? Can, the manip() function be made ?

Comment: It's absolutely not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Please say me where I am not clear

Comment: You can read, edit, and evaluate user code in runtime, yes.

Comment: You cannot change what's done inside one function from another function. You should describe what you want to do, because what you posted makes no sense at all.

Comment: I just wanted to know if its possible

Comment: You should elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve, especially after being asked to do so. Do you want to edit the code of the function in runtime? Do you want to return the object, and alter it afterwards? Do you want something else, which may be impossible? I don't know. My glass ball tells me you want to edit the code during runtime, hence why i wrote the previous comment. But it's not more than a guess.

Comment: Manipulating function value/property from outside isn't possible as far i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to

1) Expose your `obj` as a public property on your function

2) Instantiate a `myFunc` object

3) Pass that object to your `manip` function so that it can be modified

```js
function myFunc() {
  this.obj = {
    one: '1',
    two: '2'
  };
};

function manip(item, action, parameters) {
  if (action === 'add') {
    return item.obj = { ...item.obj, ...parameters };
  } else if (action === 'remove') {
    delete item.obj[parameters];
  }
}

// Instantiate a new myFunc Object
const myFuncInstance = new myFunc();

console.log(myFuncInstance.obj);

manip(
  myFuncInstance,
  'add',
  { three: '3' }
); 

console.log(myFuncInstance.obj);


manip(
  myFuncInstance,
  'remove',
  'two'
);

console.log(myFuncInstance.obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear but from what I understand, short answer is no.

Please read about [scope in JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

The object is inside the scope of the myFunc(), so it can not be accessed from anywhere other than that function.

There 3 ways you can approach this.

1) Globally define the object

this is pretty obvious, take the object outside the function

2) Pass in a pointer to the object to manip()

so in this case manip would take in a 3rd argument

```
manip(command, value, object)
```

and perform the given action on the given object

3) Pass in the function (or call it)

I am not too confident on this because the question is very unclear what the purpose of doing so is but but you can pass in a function that will return an object to manip()

```
manip(command: String, value: String, f: (..) => Object) 


myFunc(){
    ...
    return obj
}
```

manip would call this f, and get the object out of it. This would allow you to generalize manip for many objects, where you can customize the surrounding to define the set of operations that can be performed on this object. This way you encapsulate the mutation and prevent silly side effects

Answer (score 1):

If your "manip" function is inside the scope of myFunc, it can "see" your object.

```
function myFunc() {
   var obj = {
     "one" : "1",
     "two" : "2"
   };

   function manip(prop,value) {
     obj[prop] = value;
   }

   manip("three","3");

   console.log(obj);
 }

 myFunc();

// { one: '1', two: '2', three: '3' }
```

If your manip function is outside the scope of myFunc, it cannot see what you declared with "var" - the scope of obj is limited to myFunc.

Answer (score 1):

You could also define your manip function inside myFunc to perform the manipulation.

```js
function myFunc() {
   var obj = {
     "one" : "1",
     "two" : "2"
   };
  
  function manip(type, ...options) {
    switch(type) {
      case 'add':
        // perform some validation before assign
        Object.assign(obj, ...options)
        console.log({type, obj});
        break;
      case 'remove':
        // perform some validation before assign
        delete obj[options[0]]
        console.log({type, obj});
        break;
      default:
        console.log('No default actions...');
    }
    
  }
  
  manip('add', { "three" : "3" });
  manip('remove', 'two');
  
 };


myFunc();
```